# Single View to tab bar view

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

How to go into a tab based view from a Single view , CAn any one give me refrence for creating a tab based application programmatically from single view ?

Comment: Raj can please much more clarify your requirements?

Comment: im having single view while click the button its shuold display yab based views in xib?

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate and initialize the UITabeBarController and add it on your view controller/ App Delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the two:

- Go to the AppDelegate.m and change the navigation controller to a TabBarController. Then you can add to the tab bar any view you like
- Create a new DEMO application based on tabBar (attached)[image: Tabbed Application] then you can see how the delegate works and copy the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

Firsts Create all object of `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate.h` file  and use following method of `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ]];

    self.viewCon=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.viewCon.title=@"First View";

    self.fView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.FnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.fView];
    self.FnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.fView.title=@"Secound View";

    self.sView=[[SecoundViewController alloc] init];
    self.SnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.sView];
    self.SnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.sView.title=@"Third View";
    .
    .
    // create UIViewController and UINavigationController As you need 
    .
    .
    .
    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia.gif"];
    self.tbItem1=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First Page" image:img1 tag:1];
    self.viewCon.tabBarItem=self.tbItem1;

    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon.gif"];
    self.tbItem2=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Secound Page" image:img2 tag:2];
    self.fView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem2;

    UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.png"];
    self.tbItem3=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third Page" image:img3 tag:3];
    self.sView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem3;

    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.FnavCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.SnavCon];


    self.tbCon=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tbCon.viewControllers=viewArr;

    [self.window addSubview:tbCon.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**My Code is basic demo of how to create TabBar and how to add ViewController, this might be helpful for you.**

**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can create tabbar application from single view based application. Go to xib add UITabbar from objects and add delegates of that. If you did this, you have to put tabbar in every view of tabbar section. It's simple but increase repetitive code.